# Play, Ebeans: NullPointerException when starting application with multiple DBs

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I'm having an issue when trying to launch an application (using Play v2.5.10) that needs to be able to connect to two DB's (one master DB with entities and the other with time series data relating to the said entities). My project is structured as follows.
In my build.sbt I have the following line

```
playEbeanModels in Compile := Seq("models.sentinel.*", "models.kodi.*")
```

in my application.conf I have the following pointing to the package containing the Entity

```
ebean.sentinel = ["models.sentinel.*"]
ebean.kodi = ["models.kodi.*"]
```

and configured the datasources as such

```
db {
  sentinel {
    hikaricp {
      dataSourceClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"
      maxLifetime=900000
      idleTimeout=300000
      maximumPoolSize=100
      minimumIdle=5
      username = sentinel
      password = sentinelAdmin

      dataSource {
        user = *******
        password = "*************"
        databaseName = "sentinel"
        serverName = "**********"
        portNumber = 3306
        interactiveClient=true
        useUnicode=true
        autoReconnect=true
        prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=2048
        cachePrepStmts=true
        prepStmtCacheSize=250
        useServerPrepStmts=true
      }
    }
  }
  kodi {
    hikaricp {
      dataSourceClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"
      maxLifetime=900000
      idleTimeout=300000
      maximumPoolSize=100
      minimumIdle=5
         username = kodi
        password = kodiAdmin
      dataSource {
        user = ******
        password = "********"
        databaseName = "kodi"
        serverName = "********"
        portNumber = 3306
        interactiveClient=true
        useUnicode=true
        autoReconnect=true
        prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=2048
        cachePrepStmts=true
        prepStmtCacheSize=250
        useServerPrepStmts=true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I try and compile and following stack trace (truncated to fit)

```
[info] Babel compiling on 10 source(s)
[warn] application - Logger configuration in conf files is deprecated and has no effect. Use a logback configuration file instead.
[info] application - Creating Pool for datasource 'sentinel'
[info] p.a.d.DefaultDBApi - Database [sentinel] connected at jdbc:mysql://*********:3306/sentinel
[info] application - Creating Pool for datasource 'kodi'
[info] p.a.d.DefaultDBApi - Database [kodi] connected at jdbc:mysql://*********:3306/kodi
[error] i.e.s.d.BeanDescriptorManager - Error in deployment
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at io.ebeanservice.docstore.api.support.DocStoreBeanBaseAdapter.derive(DocStoreBeanBaseAdapter.java:323)
    at io.ebeanservice.docstore.api.support.DocStoreBeanBaseAdapter.<init>(DocStoreBeanBaseAdapter.java:110)
    at io.ebeanservice.docstore.none.NoneDocStoreBeanAdapter.<init>(NoneDocStoreBeanAdapter.java:17)
    at io.ebeanservice.docstore.none.NoneDocStoreFactory.createAdapter(NoneDocStoreFactory.java:24)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.createDocStoreBeanAdapter(BeanDescriptorManager.java:260)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptor.<init>(BeanDescriptor.java:491)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readEntityRelationships(BeanDescriptorManager.java:761)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.deploy(BeanDescriptorManager.java:323)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.InternalConfiguration.<init>(InternalConfiguration.java:141)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:127)
[error] i.e.s.d.BeanDescriptorManager - Error in deployment
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at io.ebeanservice.docstore.api.support.DocStoreBeanBaseAdapter.derive(DocStoreBeanBaseAdapter.java:323)
    at io.ebeanservice.docstore.api.support.DocStoreBeanBaseAdapter.<init>(DocStoreBeanBaseAdapter.java:110)
    at io.ebeanservice.docstore.none.NoneDocStoreBeanAdapter.<init>(NoneDocStoreBeanAdapter.java:17)
    at io.ebeanservice.docstore.none.NoneDocStoreFactory.createAdapter(NoneDocStoreFactory.java:24)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.createDocStoreBeanAdapter(BeanDescriptorManager.java:260)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptor.<init>(BeanDescriptor.java:491)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readEntityRelationships(BeanDescriptorManager.java:761)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.deploy(BeanDescriptorManager.java:323)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.InternalConfiguration.<init>(InternalConfiguration.java:141)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:127)
[info] application - ApplicationTimer demo: Starting application at 2017-03-29T13:44:16.602Z
[error] application - 

! @73fn6o32j - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NullPointerException
  at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.<init>(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:35)
  at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.class(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:32)
  while locating play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions
  at play.db.ebean.EbeanModule.bindings(EbeanModule.java:21):
Binding(class play.api.db.evolutions.DynamicEvolutions to ConstructionTarget(class play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions) eagerly) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
  while locating play.api.db.evolutions.DynamicEvolutions
  while locating play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider
  at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsModule.<init>(EvolutionsModule.scala:20):
Binding(class play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions to ProviderConstructionTarget(class play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider) eagerly) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
  while locating play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.ebeanservice.docstore.api.support.DocStoreBeanBaseAdapter.derive(DocStoreBeanBaseAdapter.java:323)
    at io.ebeanservice.docstore.api.support.DocStoreBeanBaseAdapter.<init>(DocStoreBeanBaseAdapter.java:110)
    ..............................
    at io.ebean.EbeanServerFactory.createInternal(EbeanServerFactory.java:108)
    at io.ebean.EbeanServerFactory.create(EbeanServerFactory.java:67)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.lambda$start$3(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:49)
    at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1288)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.start(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:49)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.<init>(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:38)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions$$FastClassByGuice$$52c94231.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$FastClassProxy.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:89)
    ..............................
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1015)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1054)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:405)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:400)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider.get$lzycompute(EvolutionsModule.scala:49)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider.get(EvolutionsModule.scala:49)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider.get(EvolutionsModule.scala:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:62)
    ..............................
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:180)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:99)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:84)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:181)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:137)
    ..............................
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:126)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:118)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$AdaptedForkJoinTask.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:121)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

2) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NullPointerException
  at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.<init>(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:35)
  at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.class(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:32)
  while locating play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions
  at play.db.ebean.EbeanModule.bindings(EbeanModule.java:21):
Binding(class play.api.db.evolutions.DynamicEvolutions to ConstructionTarget(class play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions) eagerly) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
  while locating play.api.db.evolutions.DynamicEvolutions
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.ebeanservice.docstore.api.support.DocStoreBeanBaseAdapter.derive(DocStoreBeanBaseAdapter.java:323)
    at io.ebeanservice.docstore.api.support.DocStoreBeanBaseAdapter.<init>(DocStoreBeanBaseAdapter.java:110)
    ..............................
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:127)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:44)
    at io.ebean.EbeanServerFactory.createInternal(EbeanServerFactory.java:108)
    at io.ebean.EbeanServerFactory.create(EbeanServerFactory.java:67)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.lambda$start$3(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:49)
    at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1288)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.start(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:49)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.<init>(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:38)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions$$FastClassByGuice$$52c94231.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$FastClassProxy.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:111)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:268)
    ..............................
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:99)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:84)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:181)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:137)
    ..............................
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$AdaptedForkJoinTask.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:121)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

2 errors]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:178)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:128)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:128)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:126)
    at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:231)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:126)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:118)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
Caused by: com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NullPointerException
  at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.<init>(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:35)
  at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.class(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:32)
  while locating play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions
  at play.db.ebean.EbeanModule.bindings(EbeanModule.java:21):
Binding(class play.api.db.evolutions.DynamicEvolutions to ConstructionTarget(class play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions) eagerly) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
  while locating play.api.db.evolutions.DynamicEvolutions
  while locating play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider
  at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsModule.<init>(EvolutionsModule.scala:20):
Binding(class play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions to ProviderConstructionTarget(class play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider) eagerly) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
  while locating play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.ebeanservice.docstore.api.support.DocStoreBeanBaseAdapter.derive(DocStoreBeanBaseAdapter.java:323)
    at io.ebeanservice.docstore.api.support.DocStoreBeanBaseAdapter.<init>(DocStoreBeanBaseAdapter.java:110)
    at io.ebeanservice.docstore.none.NoneDocStoreBeanAdapter.<init>(NoneDocStoreBeanAdapter.java:17)
    ..............................
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.InternalConfiguration.<init>(InternalConfiguration.java:141)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:127)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:44)
    at io.ebean.EbeanServerFactory.createInternal(EbeanServerFactory.java:108)
    at io.ebean.EbeanServerFactory.create(EbeanServerFactory.java:67)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.lambda$start$3(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:49)
    at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1288)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.start(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:49)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.<init>(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:38)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions$$FastClassByGuice$$52c94231.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$FastClassProxy.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:111)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:268)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    ..............................
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1015)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1054)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:405)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:400)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider.get$lzycompute(EvolutionsModule.scala:49)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider.get(EvolutionsModule.scala:49)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider.get(EvolutionsModule.scala:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72)
    ..............................
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1085)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.loadEagerSingletons(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:180)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:99)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:84)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:181)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:137)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:166)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:163)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
    ..............................
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

2) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NullPointerException
  at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.<init>(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:35)
  at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.class(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:32)
  while locating play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions
  at play.db.ebean.EbeanModule.bindings(EbeanModule.java:21):
Binding(class play.api.db.evolutions.DynamicEvolutions to ConstructionTarget(class play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions) eagerly) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
  while locating play.api.db.evolutions.DynamicEvolutions
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.ebeanservice.docstore.api.support.DocStoreBeanBaseAdapter.derive(DocStoreBeanBaseAdapter.java:323)
    at io.ebeanservice.docstore.api.support.DocStoreBeanBaseAdapter.<init>(DocStoreBeanBaseAdapter.java:110)
    at io.ebeanservice.docstore.none.NoneDocStoreBeanAdapter.<init>(NoneDocStoreBeanAdapter.java:17)
    at io.ebeanservice.docstore.none.NoneDocStoreFactory.createAdapter(NoneDocStoreFactory.java:24)
    ..............................
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:127)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:44)
    at io.ebean.EbeanServerFactory.createInternal(EbeanServerFactory.java:108)
    at io.ebean.EbeanServerFactory.create(EbeanServerFactory.java:67)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.lambda$start$3(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:49)
    at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1288)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.start(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:49)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.<init>(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:38)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions$$FastClassByGuice$$52c94231.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$FastClassProxy.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:111)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:268)
    ..............................
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:180)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:99)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:84)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:181)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:137)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:166)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:163)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
    ..............................
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

2 errors
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:470)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:184)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:99)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:84)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:181)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:137)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:166)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:163)
```

I've been spinning my wheels on this for the past week and would really appreciate any insight into what might be causing this

Comment: Move your properties `dataSource`to outside of `hikaricp`, I guess it will do the trick.

Comment: @pedroct92 I tied that with no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and cleaned out my ivy cache. I re-ran the sbt build and it resolved the correct dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

This is how your configuration should look like:

```
db {
  sentinel {
    driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url="**********"
    username=****
    password="*******"
    hikaricp {
        ...
    }
  }

  kodi {
    driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url="******"
    username=****
    password="****"
    hikaricp {
        ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried that with no luck

Comment: What version of the ebean plugin are you using? Does it work when you only configure one database?

Comment: I'm using version 4.0.0-M2 and yes, it does work when only one database is configured.

Comment: For me the configuration above worked for two databases, but I'm using the 3.0.0 ebean plugin...

Comment: I'll try that and let you know how it goes.